# angular2 creating and populating radio button group with ngFor

Tags: angular

I am basically iterating over a JSON object array and trying to create radio buttons pre-selected with values:

```
<div *ngFor="let task of tasks">
    <p>
        <mdl-textfield label="What task" type="text" formControlName="what_task" floating-label [ngModel]="task.what_task"></mdl-textfield>
    </p>

    <p>
        How often do you perform?<br/>
        <mdl-radio value="Daily" formControlName="how_often" mdl-ripple [(ngModel)]="task.how_often">Daily once</mdl-radio>
        <mdl-radio value="Weekly" formControlName="how_often" mdl-ripple [(ngModel)]="task.how_often">Weekly once</mdl-radio>
    </p><br>

</div>
```

Consider I have two tasks, one has value of how_often set to 'Daily' and the second has it set to 'Weekly'. Two sets of radio buttons are created but both get value 'Weekly' i.e. of the second task.

What am I doing wrong in this case? What is the correct way to generate radio button pairs with ngFor?

**UPDATE:**

My entire template:

```
<mdl-expansion-panel-group>
    <mdl-expansion-panel *ngFor="let task of tasks">
        <mdl-expansion-panel-header>
            <mdl-expansion-panel-header-list-content><h6>{{task.what_task}}</h6></mdl-expansion-panel-header-list-content>
        </mdl-expansion-panel-header>
        <mdl-expansion-panel-content>
            <mdl-expansion-panel-body>

                <form [formGroup]="form">

                    <!-- What task -->
                    <p>
                        <mdl-textfield label="What task" type="text" formControlName="what_task" floating-label [ngModel]="task.what_task"></mdl-textfield>
                    </p>


                    <!-- How often -->
                    <p>
                        How often do you perform?<br/>
                        <mdl-radio value="Daily" formControlName="how_often" mdl-ripple >Daily once</mdl-radio>
                        <mdl-radio value="Weekly" formControlName="how_often" mdl-ripple >Weekly once</mdl-radio>
                    </p><br>

                    <!-- How important -->
                    <p>
                        How important it is?<br/>
                        <mdl-radio value="Extremely" formControlName="how_important" mdl-ripple [ngModel]="task.how_important">Extremely important</mdl-radio>
                        <mdl-radio value="Rather" formControlName="how_important" mdl-ripple [ngModel]="task.how_important">Rather important</mdl-radio>
                    </p><br>

                    <!-- Why -->
                    <p>
                        <mdl-textfield rows="3" label="Why do you need to perform" type="text" [ngModel]="task.why_perform" formControlName="why_perform"  floating-label></mdl-textfield>
                    </p>

                    <!-- Why important -->
                    <p>
                        <mdl-textfield rows="3" label="Why is it important" type="text" [ngModel]="task.why_important" formControlName="why_important" floating-label></mdl-textfield>
                    </p>

                    <!-- Possible improvement -->
                    <p>
                        <mdl-textfield rows="3" label="What improvement you can think of" type="text" 
                        [ngModel]="task.possible_improvement" formControlName="possible_improvement" floating-label></mdl-textfield>
                    </p>


                    <!-- Existing solutions -->
                    <p>
                        <mdl-textfield rows="3" label="What are the tools/solutions that you use" type="text" [ngModel]="task.existing_solutions" formControlName="existing_solutions" floating-label></mdl-textfield>
                    </p>

                    <!-- How important improvement -->
                    <p>
                        How important is the improvement?<br/>
                        <mdl-radio value="Extremely" formControlName="how_important_improvement" mdl-ripple [ngModel]="task.how_important_improvement">Extremely important</mdl-radio>
                        <mdl-radio value="Rather" formControlName="how_important_improvement" mdl-ripple [ngModel]="task.how_important_improvement">Rather important</mdl-radio>
                    </p><br>

                    <!-- Advantages of improvement -->
                    <p>
                        How important is the improvement?<br/>
                        <mdl-radio value="Saves money" formControlName="advantages_of_improvement" mdl-ripple [ngModel]="task.advantages_of_improvement">Saves money</mdl-radio>
                        <mdl-radio value="Saves time" formControlName="advantages_of_improvement" mdl-ripple [ngModel]="task.advantages_of_improvement">Saves time</mdl-radio>
                        <mdl-radio value="Saves efforts" formControlName="advantages_of_improvement" mdl-ripple [ngModel]="task.advantages_of_improvement">Saves rfforts</mdl-radio>

                    </p><br>


                    <p>
                        <button mdl-button (click)="updateTask(task, task.id)" [disabled]="!form.valid" mdl-button-type="raised" mdl-ripple mdl-colored="primary">Submit</button>
                    </p>
                </form>

                <div style="color: red;" *ngIf="errorMessage">
                    <h4>{{errorMessage}}</h4>
                </div>

                <div style="color: green;" *ngIf="successMessage">
                    <h4>{{successMessage}}</h4>
                </div>

            </mdl-expansion-panel-body>
        </mdl-expansion-panel-content>
    </mdl-expansion-panel>
</mdl-expansion-panel-group>
```

and in component I have:

```
    this.form = fb.group({
      'what_task': this.what_task,
      'how_often': this.how_often,
      'how_important': this.how_important,
      'why_perform': this.why_perform,
      'why_important': this.why_important,
      'possible_improvement': this.possible_improvement,
      'existing_solutions': this.existing_solutions,
      'how_important_improvement': this.how_important_improvement,
      'advantages_of_improvement': this.advantages_of_improvement,

    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getTasks();
  }

  public updateTask(task, taskId) {
    console.log(task, taskId);

    this.steps=task.steps; 


    this.task.what_task=this.form.value.what_task
    this.task.how_often=this.form.value.how_often
    this.task.how_important=this.form.value.how_important
    this.task.why_perform=this.form.value.why_perform
    this.task.why_important=this.form.value.why_important
    this.task.possible_improvement=this.form.value.possible_improvement
    this.task.existing_solutions=this.form.value.existing_solutions
    this.task.how_important_improvement=this.form.value.how_important_improvement
    this.task.advantages_of_improvement=this.form.value.advantages_of_improvement

    this.taskService.updateTask(this.task, taskId).subscribe(
      task => {
        this.task = task,

        this.errorMessage=null;
        this.successMessage='Task updated successfully!'
      },
      error =>  {
        this.errorMessage = <any>error;
        this.successMessage=null;

      })


  }
```

Comment: Have you fixed this issue?

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, I had to change to  [ngModel], I was writing it as: [(ngModel)]

Comment: ok, so you decided not to go with ReactiveForms at all then?

Comment: Wait I will just answe my own question with whatever is now working, actually it's been a few days and I actually forgot what I had done..

Comment: Oh yes I remember, I decided to follow a different approach so I am not looping over tasks and then populating forms each time for a specific task, instead I loop over tasks in a different div and then whatever task is selected is just populated in a single reactive form

Comment: Cool, glad it is working

Comment: However I have given +1 to your answer as the plunkr is working. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is they are all (all 4 of them) referencing the same formControl as seen here: `formControlName="how_often"`.

By making a `FormArray`, which matches each task, you will achieve the desired result.

taskform.component.ts

```
createFormGroup() {
  return this.fb.group({
      'what_task': this.what_task,
      'how_often': this.how_often,
      'how_important': this.how_important,
      'why_perform': this.why_perform,
      'why_important': this.why_important,
      'possible_improvement': this.possible_improvement,
      'existing_solutions': this.existing_solutions,
      'how_important_improvement': this.how_important_improvement,
      'advantages_of_improvement': this.advantages_of_improvement,
  });
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.getTasks();

  this.formArray = new FormArray([]);
  for(const task of this.tasks) {
    this.formArray.push(this.createFormGroup());
  }
}
```

taskform.component.html

```
<mdl-expansion-panel *ngFor="let task of tasks; let i = index">
    <form [formGroup]="formArray.at(i)">
```

In the template I only highlighted the major changes.  Other than those lines, your template should be able to stay as is.

I have created a sample plunkr here: https://plnkr.co/edit/qIZiBPAjJeYG73c3vmhb?p=preview

Comment: You should remove the `ngModel` (and any references to @angular/forms) and make sure you use the correct `formControlName`.  Without seeing your form group structure, I'm not sure.

Comment: I have updated my question with entire template and corresponding component. Could you perhaps tell now?

Comment: So the biggest issue is that you have one formGroup which corresponds to one task, but you have multiple tasks that you are trying to fit into the formGroup

Comment: wouldn't that be possible? My text controls are working fine, I am facing issue with Radio group though :(

Comment: @Nitish please take a look at my update answer and let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: Hey @Chris first of all thanks for taking efforts, I tried this but unfortunately it as good as had no effect. I am still facing the same issue (I had to move the lines bellow getTasks() to the success callback of getTask() otherwise it was giving me error), but I am still seeing details of second tasks assigned to both the tasks..

Comment: Also I am printing this.formArray after pushing into it and the result you can see in my question

Comment: @Nitish I added a plunkr link in my answer.  Please let me know if that makes it more clear.